# An error while running uitable

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-uitable

I am trying to run this program. but I am getting an error which is

```
Attempt to call constructor uitable with incorrect letter case.
Error in simple_gui2 (line 11)
```

Where I am wrong? Code:

```
f = figure('Position',[200 200 400 150]); 
dat = rand(3);

cnames = {'X-Data','Y-Data','Z-Data'}; 
rnames = {'First','Second','Third'};  
t = uitable('Parent',f,'Data',dat,'ColumnName',cnames,... 
        'RowName',rnames,'Position',[20 20 360 100]);
```

Comment: you're code runs properly on my machine, without any errors or warnings. Do you have any multiple overloaded variable definitions? Try to `clear all` variables before running your script.

Answer (score 0):

This could because you have a class or function on your path called something comparable to uitable with a different case letter in it, such as Uitable or uiTable. There is a tool on the file exchange called [whichx](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9076-whichx) that can help find duplicates if this is the issue.